# Keep getting "error LNK1104: cannot open file 'boost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_41.lib"

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, linker, boost-thread

Trying to get familiar with the Boost files and I keep encountering this fatal error

```
error LNK1104: cannot open file 'boost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_41.lib'
```

I had to convert the program from VS 2008 to VS 2010, could this be the cause?

Comment: You will have to rebuild boost and any other dll dependency for your application with VS2010. It's not safe to mix Visual Studio versions or configurations in the same application because of incompatible crts and also having more than 1 independent heap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, this is the cause, you need to rebuild boost based on your new compiler  VS 2010.